# What are the chances that a Wither will drop a Nether Star?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been thinking about battling the Wither. Are the drop chances of a Nether Star 100% or should I reconsider the fight?

Comment: 100% drop rate, and the star is immune to blast damage, though will still burn in lava.

Answer (score 10):

If you kill the Wither, it is *guaranteed* to drop one Nether Star and some XP. From the [Minecraft Wiki page for the Wither:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither)

> ### Drops
>
> The wither drops 1 nether star upon death. The Looting enchantment does not work on the wither. It drops 50 experience when killed by a player or tamed wolf.

Answer (score 2):

The Wither drops one star upon death and there is a 100% chance that is will do so.